# del /s /q "file location" isn't working

Tags: batch-file, delete-directory

```
    del /S /Q "C:\TEST\TESTFOLDER\"
```

isn't actually deleting TESTFOLDER.

Answer (score 4):

`Del` command is used for deleting files. If you want to delete folder, you should use `rmdir` with `/s /q` switches to force delete the folder and all it's files without prompt

```
rmdir /S /Q "C:\TEST\TESTFOLDER\"
```